# How to achieve this grid like design?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, tailwind-css

So I am creating a catalogue section for e-commerce site and my designer made this layout. I think its really cool but I'm not sure how to implement this. I have been trying using table but I'm not getting desired result.

[image]

I am thinking of using grid system but let me know what guys are thinking.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Answering my own question, I got this video from youtube and its really good: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rg7Fvvl3taU

Comment: @AshutoshDash Because your question is not of high quality. It misses for example a code sample of what you have tried so far.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can make use of Tailwind  CSS `grid` classes like this to create a similar grid structure.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="mx-auto mt-16 grid w-8/12 grid-cols-3 text-white grid-rows-3 gap-4 bg-slate-200">
  <div class="row-span-2 flex items-center justify-center rounded-lg bg-gradient-to-l from-green-400 to-green-900">block1</div>
  <div class="col-span-2 flex items-center justify-center rounded-lg bg-gradient-to-l from-green-400 to-green-900">block2</div>
  <div class="row-span-2 flex items-center justify-center rounded-lg bg-gradient-to-l from-green-400 to-green-900">block4</div>
  <div class="flex items-center justify-center rounded-lg bg-gradient-to-l from-green-400 to-green-900">block5</div>
  <div class="flex items-center justify-center rounded-lg bg-gradient-to-l from-green-400 to-green-900">block3</div>
  <div class="flex h-40 items-center justify-center rounded-lg bg-gradient-to-l from-green-400 to-green-900">block6</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this by using following way. As per design, I've given `item3` a little extra width as compared to left and right column widths. And, `item4` is having a little greater height than `item6`.

I hope it helps you.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  max-width: 600px;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  border: 1px solid magenta;
  margin-inline: auto;
  padding: 1em;
  /*  Grid  */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 1em;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

#item1 {
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}

#item2 {
  grid-column: 2 / 4;
}

#item3 {
  width: 115%;
  grid-row: 2 / 4;
  grid-column-start: 2;
}

#item6 {
  order: 5;
}

#item4 {
  width: 85%;
  height: 80%;
  justify-self: end;
}

#item6 {
  width: 85%;
  height: 120%;
  justify-self: end;
  align-self: end;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item" id="item1">1</div>
  <div class="item" id="item2">2</div>
  <div class="item" id="item3">3</div>
  <div class="item" id="item4">4</div>
  <div class="item" id="item5">5</div>
  <div class="item" id="item6">6</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use grid for that. As you have tagged your question with tailwind, I will use that.

You can use the `grid` and `grid-cols-n` and `grid-rows-n` classes to define your grid. Then you can use `col-span-n` and `row-span-n` to stretch your divs over columns and rows. Like:

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-3 grid-rows-3 gap-4 w-8/12 mx-auto mt-16">
  <div class="row-span-2 rounded-lg bg-green-400 flex justify-center items-center">block</div>
  <div class="col-span-2 rounded-lg bg-green-400 flex justify-center items-center">block</div>
  <div class="row-span-2 rounded-lg bg-green-400 flex justify-center items-center">block</div>
  <div class="rounded-lg bg-green-400 flex justify-center items-center">block</div>
  <div class="rounded-lg bg-green-400 flex justify-center items-center">block</div>
  <div class="h-40 rounded-lg bg-green-400 flex justify-center items-center">block</div>
</div>
```

[See this working example in tailwind play.](https://play.tailwindcss.com/8ZhNue89Uz)

I saw that the bottom right square in your example was slightly higher than the others. You can achieve that by making your grid for example 3x9 and add col-span and row-span based on that grid and adding some height to a few divs.

EDIT: I have added an example of this in the tailwind playground.

You could also take a look at [this video from tailwind labs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WJDw1J7FZnE).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

you can check my pen and how to do it. But I use flex instead of grid.

HTML

```
<div class="container">


<div class="left">
     <div class="long"></div>
     <div class="short"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="rectangle"></div>
    <div class="list">
      <div class="long"></div>
      <div class="short">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.container .left {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: calc(40% - 20px);
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.container .left div {
  background: red;
}

.container .left .long {
  flex: 1
}


.container .left .short {
  height: 250px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.container .right {
  width: 60%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container .right .rectangle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: red;
}

.container .right .list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex: 1;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.container .right .long {
  width: calc(50% - 20px);
  margin-right: 20px;
  flex: 1;
  background-color: red;
}

div .right .list .short {
  width: 50%;
}

div .right .list .short div {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

div .right .list .short div:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```